# How to hover over using TestCafe?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, automated-tests, hover, testcafe

As a part of Automation testing, I want to hover over [this node.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrJFG.png) which has a complex source code. [You can find the code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLZJX.png)
. Can someone please say the code which can hover using the syntax `.hover(Selector(?))` using TestCafe.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you can select nodes in `svg` only if it's inserted into the HTML document via the `<svg>` tag. TestCafe does not support selecting elements in an `svg` that is imported from a separate document via the `<object>` tag.

There are multiple ways to select an element in TestCafe using `Selector`. To do that, you need to identify the element's distinguishing features. These might include the element's id, class, attributes, position in the DOM tree or relation to other elements. Then you need to create a `Selector` based on one of these features.

For more information on TestCafe selectors see [our documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements.html#create-selectors).